# Overlaying Multiple Time Series in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to emphasize the trends of California and overlay the other time series for the other states, preferably as very thin greyscale lines. So far, I'm able to plot the trends for California.

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hfont = {'fontname':'Times New Roman'}

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/synth-inference/synthdid/master/data/california_prop99.csv', 
sep=';', parse_dates=['Year'], index_col='Year')


df = df.sort_values(by=['State'])


df_Cali = df[df['State'] == 'California']

df_Cali = df_Cali.sort_values(by=['Year'])


df_Cali.plot(y='PacksPerCapita', color='black', linewidth=3, legend=None) 

#[(.17, .27, .57)]


plt.title('Tobacco Trends', fontsize=14, **hfont)


plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=14, **hfont)
plt.xticks(fontsize=14, rotation=45, **hfont)


plt.ylabel('Cigarette Sales Per Capita', fontsize=14, **hfont)

x_position = df_Cali.index.searchsorted('1988-01-01')

plt.vlines(x= x_position, ymin=0, ymax=300, color='red', label="Proposition 99")

plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

But, now I wish to overlay *all* of the other packs per capita trends from the original dataframe **df**, excluding California, of course. How might I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['State', 'Year'])
# ...
ax = df_Cali.plot(y='PacksPerCapita', color='black', linewidth=3,
                  legend=None, zorder=3)

for k, g in df.groupby('State'):
    if k == 'California':
        continue
    g.plot(y='PacksPerCapita', color='grey', linewidth=0.5, alpha=0.5,
           legend=None, zorder=2, ax=ax)
```

Output:

[image: overlayed multiple lines]

##### full code with alternative

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hfont = {'fontname':'Times New Roman'}

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/synth-inference/synthdid/master/data/california_prop99.csv',
                 sep=';', parse_dates=['Year'], index_col='Year')

df = df.sort_values(by=['State', 'Year'])

ax = plt.subplot()

for k, g in df.groupby('State', sort=False):
    if k == 'California':
        g.plot(y='PacksPerCapita', color='black', linewidth=3, legend=None, zorder=3, ax=ax)
    else:
        g.plot(y='PacksPerCapita', color='grey', linewidth=0.5, alpha=0.5, legend=None, ax=ax, zorder=2) 

# title/ticks
plt.title('Tobacco Trends', fontsize=14, **hfont)
plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=14, **hfont)
plt.xticks(fontsize=14, rotation=45, **hfont)
plt.ylabel('Cigarette Sales Per Capita', fontsize=14, **hfont)

# red line
x_position = df_Cali.index.searchsorted('1988-01-01')
plt.vlines(x= x_position, ymin=0, ymax=300, color='red', label="Proposition 99")

plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: This is close to what I desire, but notice how the overlaid lines are connected. They should not be. There should be one line for all the 38 states, instead of being connected as the now are with this solution.

Comment: @Jared I see what you mean, I though the data was already sorted but no, check the update

Comment: Yeah I figured that was the issue! But just so I am understanding you, you wanted me to put the now-edited code after `plt.show()`, right? That is, everything following `#...` is meant to go below `plt.show()`?

Comment: No, put the loop just after your original `df_Cali.plot` (but I see you figured it out). I didn't want to clutter the answer ;)

Comment: I provided a full code with a slightly different approach (all in the loop) ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is the full example that does what I want.

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hfont = {'fontname':'Times New Roman'}

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/synth-inference/synthdid/master/data/california_prop99.csv', 
sep=';', parse_dates=['Year'], index_col='Year')


df = df.sort_values(by=['State', 'Year'])


df_Cali = df[df['State'] == 'California']

df_Cali = df_Cali.sort_values(by=['Year'])

ax = df_Cali.plot(y='PacksPerCapita', color='black', linewidth=3,
                  legend=None, zorder=3)

for k, g in df.groupby('State'):
    if k == 'California':
        continue
    g.plot(y='PacksPerCapita', color='grey', linewidth=0.5, alpha=0.5,
           legend=None, zorder=2, ax=ax) 
       


plt.title('Tobacco Trends', fontsize=14, **hfont)


plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=14, **hfont)
plt.xticks(fontsize=14, rotation=45, **hfont)


plt.ylabel('Cigarette Sales Per Capita', fontsize=14, **hfont)

x_position = df_Cali.index.searchsorted('1988-01-01')

plt.vlines(x= x_position, ymin=0, ymax=300, color='red', label="Proposition 99")

plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```